# Cloudflare redirect to waiting room loop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, captcha

Basically the problem is, there is a website which I'm trying to scrape using selinium/pupetteer. Issue is, when I'm using proxy and not using headless mode I get presented with the clouldflare waiting room where I'm required to click on the checkbox to move ahead. But, instead of showing me the website itself it redirect me back to the same waiting room as if it was not able to save the captcha solved cookie or some other issue. I tried solving the captcha and going through this process 20+ times, and it still keeps redirecting me to same waiting room page.

The moment, I remove proxy and use main IP it immediately, redirects me to the main website after verifying in cloudflare.

My code, just in undetected_chromdriver to replicate the thing.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc 
import time
options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = False 

proxy = 'p.webshare.io:80'
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=username:password')

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options) 
driver.get("https://mantrivip.in/#/login") 
driver.maximize_window() 
inp = input('')
driver.close()
```

The website having cloudflare is: mantrivip.com and I'm using webshare rotating private proxies

I tried using one specific proxy, randomly choosen and got same error. I tried buying private proxies, from webshare company itself and got same issues.

Just to clearify, the proxies are working fine I tried using one of the proxy in my network setting and was able to get to the site but only the selinium/pupeeter creates issue